# Closest Pair of Points: QuickCP termination check

Tags: computational-geometry, termination

In *A Simple Yet Fast Algorithm for the Closest-Pair Problem Using Sorted
Projections on Multi-Dimensions*, Mehmet E. Dalkılıç and Serkan Ergun present algorithm *QuickCP* for finding the closest pair, discussing the planar case more often than other *Multi-Dimensions*.

##### Algoritm 1 $\text{QuickCP}(P)$

---

// $P = \{P_1, P_2, \dots , P_n\}$ *where* $P_i = (c₁_i,c₂_i,\dots,c_{ki})$ *i.e.*, $n$ *input points in* $k$ *dimensions*
**for *d* = 1 to *k* do**  // for every dimension *d*
    $A(d) \leftarrow sortByDimension_d(P)$ // Sort P by x(y …)-values, store in $A(d) (A$scending) i.e.,
                                           ${A(d)(1), A(d)(2), \dots , A(d)(n)}$
**end for**
$d_{min} \leftarrow \infty$
**for** *r* = 1 **to** *n*-1 **do**   // *at most n*-1 *rounds*
    **for *d* = 1 to *k* do**   // *for every dimension d*
        $\Delta{_{min}}(d) \leftarrow \infty$
        **for** *i* = 1 **to** *n - r* **do**
            $\Delta{_d} \leftarrow A(d)(i+r)\text .d - A(d)(i)\text .d$   // *A(j).d is the value of A(j) in dimension d*
            $\Delta{_{min}}(d) \leftarrow min(\Delta{_{min}}(d), \Delta{_d})$
            $distance \leftarrow$ Eucledian distance between $A(d)(i+r) \text{ and } A(d)(i)$
            $d_{min} \leftarrow min(d_{min}, distance)$
        **end for**
    **end for**
    **if** $d_{min} \lt \displaystyle{\sqrt {\sum_d (\Delta{_{min}}(d))^2 }}$ **then**
        **break**   // *Termination Condition*
    **end if**
**end for**

---

As presented in the paper named, the termination condition is checked at the end of every iteration through all the dimensions. Initialising $\Delta{_{min}}(d) \leftarrow 0$,

Is it correct to instead apply it for each dimension individually/after each inner loop?

Comment: Yes, that should indeed be the case.  The termination test checks whether it is farther away than the optimal pair, and if it's already farther away using the projection of a subset of the dimensions, it has to be further away in the full space.  I would be surprised if the authors didn't already try this optimization; why don't you try it?

Comment: You can implement the algorithm and submit it as a solution for [Closest Pair (Uniform)@kattis.com](https://open.kattis.com/problems/closestpair1) and [Closest Pair@kattis.com](https://open.kattis.com/problems/closestpair2).